# Retrieve all rows in a SmartSheet using Python SDK

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am trying to retrieve all rows in a smartsheet via the python sdk using this function:

```
for row in range(1,sheet.totalRowCount+1):
print sheet[row][0]
```

This works well in a test sheet with sample data. However, when I run the same exact lines of code on the target sheet with "live" data, I receive the error below:

> C:\Desktop\Python\smartsheetclient\client_1_1.pyc in
>   newFromAPI(cls, fields, row)    1329         column =
>   row.sheet.getColumnById(fields['columnId'])    1330
>   row.logger.info("newFromAPI: column: %r", column)
>   -> 1331         cell = Cell(row, column, fields['value'], type=fields['type'],    1332
>   displayValue=fields.get('displayValue', None),    1333
>   hyperlink=fields.get('hyperlink', None),
>
> KeyError: 'value'

What causes this error and how can I remedy it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of the SDK?

On Feb 24, I made a change to the newFromAPI() classmethod of the Cell class to not blindly assume that the 'value' attribute would be present.

Based on the stack trace you published, I *think* that will resolve this issue for you.

If it doesn't, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

PlansSheet = m_smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

for row in PlansSheet.rows:

```
       firstRows.append(row.__getattr__('id'))
```